# Run various functions on input then output to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a macro that takes an input from a cell in a column, removes text and spaces, shortens to last 13 digits, then outputs into next column over.

I was shown a bit of code in a previous question which uses regex to remove the text (I had previously got the spaces to be removed ok). However, I'm not sure how I can run the function and output to cell with my current code.

Currently all it does is shorten to 13 digits, so I think the function isn't being run/called correctly.

Current macro is:

```
Sub RemoveSpaces_Click()

i = 7
j = 7

Do While ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    InputString = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

    removeAlpha (InputString) ' <--- How to call this?

    ' Right() after removing to avoid text counting as length

    InputString = Right(InputString, 13)

    j = j + 1

    ' Output to second column to preserve original input

    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = InputString

    i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub

Function removeAlpha(strInput As String) As String

    strInput = Replace(strInput, " ", "")

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]"
        .Global = True
         removeAlpha = .Replace(strInput, "")
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: `InputString = removeAlpha (InputString) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run automatically, as long as you have something in A7, it will use the text in A7 and run it through your function. The function will use the data from the `InputString`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveSpaces_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim InputString As String
Dim OutputString As String
Dim ResultString As String

i = 7
j = 7

' If A7 is not empty continue and continue the loop until cell in column A is empty
Do While ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

    ' This string will contain data from A7
    InputString = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)

    ' This will use the InputString value in the function and save it to OutputString
    OutputString = removeAlpha(InputString) ' This will be called automatically

    ' Right() after removing to avoid text counting as length
    ' Use the OutputString in the Right-function and save to ResultString
    ResultString = Right(OutputString, 13)

    ' Loop incremental
    j = j + 1

    ' Output to second column to preserve original input
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = ResultString

    ' Loop incremental for your rows (7, 8 etc.)
    i = i + 1

    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, although I know what the macro is doing! That said, adding the 'Option Explicit' and various definitions hasn't worked.

Comment: Try again with the updated version. Tried to comment it for you.

Comment: Use F8 to step through your code. You can follow the process when using that and see how the macro runs.

Comment: Brilliant! Adding the extra variables has done the trick.I guess it had to define a variable for the removeAlpha(InputString) to be saved as?

Comment: Exactly :-) Glad it worked. Also be aware that you do not use `j` anywhere.